# Assign multiple column variables from oracle query to multiple unix variable

Tags: unix

I want to know how to assign multiple columns from oracle query which return more than one row to unix variables.

My initial code is :

```
## get DB credentials #
feed=`sqlplus -s <<EOF
$1/$2
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode rollback
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
select attach_sub_folder,file_name from DC_Purge_Files_log;
/
exit
EOF`

for counter in $feed
do
    attach_sub_folder=$(echo $feed | awk -F ';' '{print $1}')
    echo 'col1:'$attach_sub_folder
    file_name=$(echo $feed | awk -F ';' '{print $2}')
    echo 'col1:'$file_name
done
```

The above code works fine when the select statement returns one records. But i want to know how to handle when select statement returns multiple records.

I tried to search in forum but couldn't find any reference hence posting the same.

Thanks in advance.
Thanks & Regards,
Sameet Patro

Comment: And what is expected behavior on multiple records? Take first or take last?

Comment: if i am able to store those columns output in two variables, then i will some operation like for ex: If column 1 have file names and column have its corresponding folder names where these files are stored. I can write a command to (sudocode) remove <column1.filename> from folder <column2.folder_name> in a for <do> <done> loop.